# Using FileHelpers, how to extract records from an uploaded Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, filehelpers

One of the bundled examples of [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) shows how to extract and insert records from/to a Microsoft Excel Worksheet as follow:

Define a class with members that correspond to the columns in the input Excel file

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class CustomersVerticalBar
{
    public string CustomerID;
    public string CompanyName;
    public string ContactName;
    public string ContactTitle;
    public string Address;
    public string City;
    public string Country;
}
```

Then use ExcelDataStorage to extract records as follow:

```
ExcelStorage provider = new ExcelStorage(typeof(CustomersVerticalBar));
provider.StartRow = 3;
provider.StartColumn = 2;           
provider.FileName = "Customers.xls";
CustomerVerticalBar[] res = (CustomerVerticalBar[]) provider.ExtractRecords();
```

The problem is if there's no input Excel file, but the input is only available as an input stream from an uploaded file (from HttpPostedFileBase for example), what would be the solution in such case since ExcelDataStorage only takes a filename as input and not an input stream?  It's OK if the solution uses some class other than ExcelDataStorage.

Comment: I'd imagine there is a better way, but the brute force option is to write the contents to a temporary file. Then use the temporary file for the class.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx

Comment: Should have mentioned that I prefer not to take that approach and/or save that as the last resort.

Comment: The suggestion to use Path.GetTempFileName() from your link is +1 :-).

Comment: FWIW, looking at the source, it appears to be using the Excel PIA interop, so I don't think it'll be able to support a different option - http://filehelpers.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/filehelpers/trunk/FileHelpers.ExcelStorage/ExcelStorage.cs?revision=752&view=markup

Answer (score 1):

You should write it to a file and then delete it if you want after the processing, since the library may need to load some of the data and not all, and it may require to refer to the file many times.